# Check if youtube app is installed

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to check whether or not an iOS user has the youtube app installed?

I want to be able to do something different with a youtube link if they don't have the youtube app.

Thanks

Comment: Check if `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:@"youtube://"];` returns `TRUE` then youtube is installed. I don't remember youtube app's URL scheme.

Comment: @0x8badf00d : I want the youtube apps URL Sceheme... can you give me if you have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure:

```
UIApplication *uiApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
BOOL ytAppInstalled = [uiApp canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://foo"]];
```

Comment: what's foo? why can't it be till URLWithString:@"youtube://"

Comment: @SamBudda Whatever, it doesn't matter.

Comment: doesn't work anymore, tried it with swift on iOS 12.2, even if YouTube is installed it returns `false`

Comment: It won't work if you don't add `youtube` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in Info.plist